# Cardinality of a vector space over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ of dimension $3$. What is the cardinality of $V$? I don't know how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any two vector spaces over a fixed field $\mathbb{F}$ of equal dimension are isomorphic, and in particular have equal cardinality.  So it may help to think about one explicit example of a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{Z}_5$ of dimension $3$.  Do you know one?

Answer (score 11):

Since $V$ is dimension $3$, we can find a basis for $V$ consisting of $3$ linearly independent vectors; we'll call them $\{u, v, w \}$.  Elements of this vector space will necessarily look like $c_1u + c_2v + c_3w$ for $c_j \in \mathbb{Z}_5$, and you can do a contradiction proof to show that each unique triple of $c_j$'s corresponds to a unique element in the vector space.

Now the problem is reduced to finding the number of distinct triples of $c_j$'s there are: $|\mathbb{Z}_5|^3 = 5^3 = 125$.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $V$ has dimension $3$ means that it's isomorphic to the coordinate space. $\mathbb{Z}_5^3$. What is the cardinality of that space?